# SingleCRS Error Code

Tags: error, lidr

I have been working with the 'lidR' package to analyze LiDAR tiles and was able to successfully complete 14 analyses on 12/1. When I started running the script on 12/2 I kept getting this error on all of my tiles, even tiles I was able to analyze the day before without issue (`proj_crs_get_datum: Object is not a SingleCRS`):

```
tile <- readLAS("w0929n1781.las")
#> proj_crs_get_datum: Object is not a singleCRS
#> proj_crs_get_datum: Object is not a singleCRS
```

I have tried deleting and reinstalling lidR, redowloading tiles and running the script again, updating my version of R from 3.6.1 to 3.6.3, looking for any and all suggestions.

Comment: This is likely coming from `rgdal`. Please use `readLASheader()` and show us the output.

Comment: By the way it is not an error. It is only a print

Comment: I got the same message when running a function over a catalog whose tile header was:
File signature:           LASF 
File source ID:           0 
Global encoding:
 - GPS Time Type: Standard GPS Time 
 - Synthetic Return Numbers: no 
 - Well Know Text: CRS is WKT 
 - Aggregate Model: false 
Project ID - GUID:        8f9dcc62-abb7-43e8-a3b5-8614358ab2be 
Version:                  1.4
System identifier:         
Generating software:      rlas R package 
File creation d/y:        0/2018
header size:              375 
Offset to point data:     1466 
Num. var. length record:  1

Comment: Point data format:        6 
Point data record length: 30 
Num. of point records:    793523 
Num. of points by return: 350851 236954 130229 54260 16692 3889 648 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Scale factor X Y Z:       0.01 0.01 0.01 
Offset X Y Z:             0 0 0 
min X Y Z:                201000 237500 759.09 
max X Y Z:                201250 237750 958.47 
Variable length records: 
   Variable length record 1 of 1 
       Description: by LAStools of rapidlasso GmbH 
       WKT OGC COORDINATE SYSTEM: COMPD_CS["NAD83(2011) / Puerto Rico and Virgin Is. + PRVD02 height - G [...] (truncated)

Comment: sorry for that awful comment :-)